# Xamarin.Android java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, intentfilter

I'm trying to receive files from external apps using Intent and Action.Send. I chose my app at chooser list and then app trying to start but it crashes:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "net.inlu.Incrypta.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/net.inlu.Incrypta-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/net.inlu.Incrypta-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]    at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1084)    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2115)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5054)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

my manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="6" android:versionName="1.0.1" package="net.inlu.Incrypta" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:logo="@drawable/Logo" android:theme="@style/StartTheme" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" android:icon="@drawable/Logo">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I've seen a lot of such issues for Android, but didn't find anuthing exactly for Xamarin.Android. May be anyone knows how to fix it.

MainActivity :

```
namespace Android.App
{
    [Activity (MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/Logo", NoHistory = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override async void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            BootStrapper.RegisterDependencies(new IoCModule());

            Intent intent = Intent;
            string action = intent.Action;
            string type = intent.Type;

            //Xamarin.Insights.Initialize (XamarinInsights.ApiKey, this);
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
            //SetContentView(Resource.Layout.splash);
            try
            {
                var srv= BootStrapper.Container.Resolve<IServiceManager>();
                var credentials = await srv.ConnectAsync();
                StartActivity(credentials != null ? typeof(BaseActivity) : typeof(LoginActivity));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                StartActivity(typeof(LoginActivity));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code for your `.BaseActivity` class - the complaint/error is that this class is not found.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla, added

Comment: Do you have attached the [Activity]-attribute to your "BaseActivity"?

Comment: @StefanWanitzek, yes, of course, currently MainActivity = BaseActivity, sorry for confusing.

Comment: I don't understand the call to StartActivity in the OnCreate-method of the activity completely. However, I ran into some problems with namespace-names that have uppercase letters in the past. Can you try to change your namespace from net.inlu.Incrypta.BaseActivity to net.inlu.incrypta.BaseActivity? (notice the lowercase I in "Incrypta").

Comment: @StefanWanitzek, just the same, it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to explicitly change the ACW(Android Callable Wrapper) name of your `MainActivity`. This can be done multiple ways, but the easiest way would be to use the `Name` property inside the `[Activity]` attribute to specify a name. You would then set that name to the name it's looking for.

i.e.

```
[Activity(Name="net.inlu.incrypta.MainActivity")]
```

**Note:** Ensure your namespace follows Java conventions in the sense of a fully qualified name.

**EX:** com.my.package.ClassName

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_5/xamarin.android_5.1/#Android_Callable_Wrapper_Naming

Comment: @JonDouglas I have the same problem. I am using a SplashActivity that calls StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity)); and I have this ClassNotFoundException MainActivity... what can be?

Comment: It works for me, for testing purpose, I added the url as a message and tap the url from the message. My problem is app open on the message tab, no new tab is open for the app.

Answer (score 0):

**My case:**
I referenced Symbol.Xamarin.EMDK. (this is a third-party library) in the Android project. I removed it and the exception disappeared, so your problem may be caused by a third-party library. Or your third-party library does not have the correct permission configuration.

Below is the configuration of my third-party library, it can also solve this issue:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.symbol.emdk.permission.EMDK" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/icon">
        <uses-library android:name="com.symbol.emdk" android:required="false" />
</application>
```