# App is getting crashed after Launching in android. Getting Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

Facing Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException issue on Xamarin.forms android. below are the details.

Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.PowerSaveModeBroadcastReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.Appname-3XnwJB9NrCGO-bCnM5uBDQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.Appname-3XnwJB9NrCGO-bCnM5uBDQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.companyname.Appname-3XnwJB9NrCGO-bCnM5uBDQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]

note: We are using VisualStudio 2019

Comment: [Please try out the below link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37947063/xamarin-android-java-lang-classnotfoundexception)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Android: Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException launching second Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48591231/xamarin-android-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-launching-second-activity)